# Background image not displaying on a link in navbar

Tags: html, css, web-applications

I've got an image of a house I want to display on my navbar as the 'home' link. I've entered some CSS to implement this but it doesn't seem to work. Could anyone help me display the image? See the image and CSS code below for clarification.

[image]

The light blue box is where the little white house should be. See below for CSS

```
html, body
{
padding:            0;
margin-right:       auto;
margin-left:        auto;
}

.navbar
{
height:             48px;
width:              100%;
background-color:   #294052;
text-align:         center;
vertical-align:     middle;
margin-bottom:      10px;
}

li
{
display:            inline;
position:           relative;
padding:            20px;
border-right:       inset 2px white;
font-size:          20px;
font-weight:        normal;
font-family:        sans-serif;
vertical-align:     middle;
padding-top:        31px;
padding-bottom:     14px;
}

a
{
text-decoration:    none;
color:              white;
}

li:hover 
{
text-decoration:    underline;
background-color:   #447294;
}

li.home
{
background-color:   #447294;
background-image:   url('home.png');
}

span
{
font-weight:        bold;
}
```

I've tried using the `display:block` fix but it just messes up the rest of my navbar.

And the HTML code...

```
<div class="navbar">
<ul>
    <a href="#"><li class="home"></li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>ABOUT</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>CyMAL: MUSEUMS, ARCHIVES AND LIBRARIES</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>CONTACT</li></a>
</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Where is the markup? Try to use double quotes url("home.png"); - The assumption is that the file home.png is in the same place/folder as the css file.

Comment: with a update, is the file "home.png" in the same place/folder/directory where you css file is?

Comment: ahhh yes thank you Jawad. I was referencing the URL from where the .html file was and not the .css. A rookie error that I shouldn't be making anymore!

Comment: No problem. We all have been there. Just don't have the T-shirt!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your background image **is** present in `li.home`; but `li.home` isn't wide enough to display anything.  Background images are like background color - they won't change the shape of the content.

Try adding some content:

```
<li class="home">home</li>
```

Or change the alignment of your bg image to `center center` to perhaps see it more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

To start debugging, I'd first try to use absolute URL to make sure that the image can be loaded.

```
li.home
{
background-color:   #447294;
background-image:   url('full_path_to_image/home.png');
}
```

Also, please provide HTML code, ideally make a ready demo at http://jsfiddle.net/ (or any other similar service). That way you'll we can help you better.

**EDIT:** After you have added the HTML code, the problem seems to be indeed the path to your image.

Here is a **working demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/tBNSU/

Comment: Tried this and it doesn't solve the issue. :/ will edit my original question with HTML Code momentarily